# Is there a Retina Enabled IDE to do some programming on the new MacBook Pro?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

From the answers to this question: [How does Eclipse work on new Retina MacBook Pros?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53717/how-does-eclipse-work-on-new-retina-macbook-pros)

It seems that Eclipse on the new Retina a display appears pretty bad. Is there an IDE that currently works well on it?

I'd like to do Javascript / jQuery / PHP on it.

Comment: Have you seen definitve proof that "text in Eclipse" is going to look bad? It may be just the case that the UI elements look more awful, but they text may be just fine, depending on how Eclipse renders its text  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53831/is-retina-text-in-a-non-retina-os-x-application-possible

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To enable a retina eclipse

From: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972

Here's the workaround:

Do "Show package contents" on the Eclipse.app.  Edit Contents/Info.plist.  Just
above

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

Place this:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

Then, log out or make a copy of the app so that OS X will notice the change. 
Now, the info window will not show "Open in Low Resolution" as checked.  Launch
Eclipse and enjoy your new retina awesomeness.

Answer (score 6):

Coda 2 (OS X) and Diet Coda (iPad3) are both optimized for retina displays.
They have built-in support for PHP, Ruby, JavaScript, and CSS, and a bunch of other stuff.
They also have HTML/CSS/JS manuals, and SFTP/FTP & Terminal built right in.
Get them at Panic Software: http://www.panic.com

Sublime Text 2 just came out, and it also has retina-support built right in.
It's available at: http://www.sublimetext.com

Comment: +1 for Coda 2. I've been using Coda "1" for years (probably more than 4) and I always thought it was excellent... Now, Coda 2 is even better: the *definitive* app to code web sites and web apps on Mac OSX :) (excellent for HTML, CSS, JS and PHP, ASP...)

Answer (score 3):

While it's not technically an IDE, Sublime Text 2 nightly build has Retina support as of build 2201 on June 17.

http://www.sublimetext.com/nightly

However, this is a nightly build that could (er, will) contain bugs.  I've been happy with it.  I do Ruby/HTML/JS/CSS with it.

Comment: No need to get the nightly anymore, it's in the stable Sublime Text 2 release now: http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how apple is providing [documentation on how to optimize for retina displays on Macs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302), it seems safe to assume that Xcode 4.3.3 should be an IDE optimized for Retina Displays.

Although depending on the Application it might be possible to get retina "Text" if a non-retina app is using Apple native text rendering API's, it just maybe that the icons /interface may look blurry if they are custom to that app.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm more of a PHP guy and i don't think X-Code is ok for that :)

Comment: I'm trying to nail down when Xcode started being retina friendly here... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54885/which-versions-of-xcode-are-not-updated-to-take-advantage-of-hidpi-retina-displa

Answer (score 0):

The whole family of IntelliJ IDEA IDE either supports retina or can be used on retina display after small changes into the Info.plist. For details, see here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87500

Answer (score 0):

Komodo Edit (free) / Komodo IDE ($$$) version 8.0 supports OS X retina display:
http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/whats-new

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm has retina support. I'm using it on my brand-spanking-new 15" Retina Macbook Pro and it looks amazing!

Besides my own subjective experience, this [blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/06/pycharm-2-5-2-better-performance-fixed-github-and-retina-ready-editor/) from June 2012 says:

> There’s a number of fixes in the IntelliJ platform including some for web developers using SASS and Node.js and also support for Retina displays in the editor.

Screenshot available [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/darcula_retina.html).

Comment: Can you provide a link or a screen shot to verify this?

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes: sure, see edit