# Is retina text in a non-retina OS X Application possible?

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

Is it possible to have a pre-retina Application have good retina text. As in MenuBar text, and textbox and textfields and other text locations as long as the original developer used native OS X text handling API's.

For applications that do their own graphics and text rendering we know that there is a difference when trying to run on a Retina display as noted by the [MacBook Pro Retina Display Analysis](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5998/macbook-pro-retina-display-analysis) (see AnandTech comparison picture below).

The example of Non-retina Google Chrome vs Safari is noted to be a worse case caused by Google doing their own thing for rending text / graphics in the Application. Does this imply that if your not doing your own text rendering you get retina text for free?

[image: AnandTech Image of non-retinaChrome vs Safari]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications using standard Cocoa APIs should get retina text for free.

This was the same way it was released with the iPhone 4 in iOS. If you used standard UIKit, you basically got it all for free, and just had to update resources, etc.

So, with a Retina MBP as of right now, many apps need to add @2X resources (for things like images, etc), but otherwise standard applications should render all other content as retina.

Comment: For example, in Word, the font drop-down (which shows names of typefaces rendered in that font) is custom and looks blocky. But the size drop-down is a simple native control with a bunch of numbers and looks perfectly sharp. (Which then makes the rest of the app worse in comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an app which forces retina text for non-retina applications.
http://retinizer.mikelpr.com