# Which versions of Xcode are not updated to take advantage of HiDPI/Retina displays?

Tags: xcode, display, macbook-pro

I've been looking over the release notes for Xcode and can't find one that says it's been enabled for HiDPI mode and the retina display MacBook Pro. By enabled, I mean that Xcode will run on the new retina hardware - not that you could make an app that will then work on Retina.

Either:

- I missed it in reading the notes
- All versions of Xcode on Lion already have this so it's not called out as new.
- No versions (publicly available - not prerelease or NDA) yet support retina displays

Has anyone figured out which versions of Xcode do not support retina?

Comment: Note: I asked this in the negative so that it could be answered without needing a developer account / NDA if and when a version shows up there first.

Comment: I think (I don't have a retina MBP myself so I can't say for sure) that the current versions of Xcode are retina enabled. See [this blog post](http://denter.org/blog/2012/06/20/xcode-on-macbook-pro-retina/) for some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current non-beta version of Xcode, 4.3.3 for Lion, works fine on a retina device but certain UI elements are not retina-enabled. Most notably the little "LCD" screen that sits in the top middle of the toolbar, it looks quite blurry on a retina MBP. Also the Play/Stop buttons, and many other UI elements.

However the text used to render your code is crisp.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.