# Retina dsiplay support on Intellj Idea for Java /JavaScript development

Tags: java, display, javascript

I have seen this question on [retina display issues while working with Eclipse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53717/how-does-eclipse-work-on-new-retina-macbook-pros) on Macbook . I have a latest personal Intellij Idea License and would like to know your views of retina display support for `Intellij Idea 12`? I am planning to buy an [11 inch Macbook Air](http://www.apple.com/in/macbookair/specs.html) and main purpose is normal net surfing + Java development on Intellij Idea . Are there any gotchas that I should take into consideration before buying?

P.S: I am not an Apple user and hence would like to make sure that I get inputs from experienced people before I make this investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ Idea 12 is a perfectly well behaved 64bit retina enabled application on Mountain Lion.

I use IntelliJ, day in, day out on Windows PCs for Enterprise Java Dev, because it's the best there is. IMHO On the Mac it's even better.